# If you roll a fair six sided die twice, what's the probability that you get the same number both times?

Tags: probability, dice

So I know that rolling a fair six-sided die twice would mean the total possible outcomes would be 36, and rolling the same number twice would be 2/36 or 1/18, but I feel like that's wrong. What am I doing that isn't right?

Comment: It always helps to use the sample space describing all possible outcomes.

Comment: Note that it is clear that the answer is $1/6$: Whatever we got on the first roll, the probability of matching it is $1/6$. But if you want to use the sample space of $36$, the "favourables" are $(1,1)$, $(2,2)$, $\dots$.

Comment: Surely it is just 1/6th? Because it only depends on the second die roll?

Comment: Why do you think there are only two ways to roll the same number twice?  You could roll a 1 two times, or you could roll a 2 two times, or a 4 two times, or a 6 two times.  There are 6 ways to roll the same number twice: 6/36.  Why did you think it was only 2/36?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this diagram might help. It's lifted from another [website](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/131614/magic-realm-probability-beginners-i), so just imagine that the 'white die' denotes your first roll, and the 'red die' denotes your second roll.

You'll notice that there are exactly $6$ pairs of rolls (out of all $36$ possible outcomes) in which the first roll equals the second roll.

[image]

The theoretical reason for this is well-explained in [amWhy's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/598818/500125).

Comment: THANK YOU. THIS MAKES SENSE. I'm not dumb, I'm just absolutely awful at probability.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which web site?

Comment: Answer isnt written.

Comment: I had convinced myself it was 1/36 and it took this big chart to fix my brain—thanks so much!

Answer (score 17):

There are six possible numbers that can be rolled twice.

For a specific number, say $1$, the probability of rolling it *twice* is equal to $$ \underbrace{\dfrac 16}_{1\text{st roll}}\;\times \;\underbrace{\dfrac 16}_{2\text{nd roll}}=\dfrac 1{36}$$ by the *rule of the product*.

Since this can happen for $2, 3, 4, 5, 6,$ as well as for $1$,

the probability of rolling the same number twice is $$6\cdot \dfrac 16\cdot \dfrac 16 = \dfrac 16$$

Comment: And so the answer is 1/6???

Comment: Yes, I stated so explicitly. The important thing is that you understand *why*, because your problems and exercises are only going to get much more complicated. So aim to get the basics down pat! You're not going to have the time (on a test or quiz) to list all possible outcomes to most problems of this sort, so please follow up with any questions if there is something you don't understand here.

Comment: Thank you, you've been very helpful. I'm awful at probability so far. Throw Algebra in front of me and I'm a math whiz!

Comment: I can in two minutes, haha.

Answer (score 6):

The first roll doesn't matter. It only sets a target. The chances of hitting a target in one roll are one in SIX, not one in three. You could have someone call out a number for the target. That doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: as you stated, there is a total of $36$ outcomes. The outcomes you're interested in are $(1,1),....$ , a total of _ outcomes out of $36$.