# Expected number of rolls until a number appears 2 times discussion

Tags: probability

I have the following problem. How many times you have to roll a die until you get two 6 or two 5 in a row.

Problems similar to this one have been discussed in the forum in links like:

[1] [Number of rolls until the same number appears 2 consecutive times](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2041425/number-of-rolls-until-the-same-number-appears-2-consecutive-times)

[2] [Expected number of rolls for fair die to get same number appear twice in a row?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747036/expected-number-of-rolls-for-fair-die-to-get-same-number-appear-twice-in-a-row)

I "solved" this problem as follows:

Let A the event of two consecutives 6 or two consecutive 5 in a row, and B the event of two consecutive equal numbers in a row. Then, it follows that:

\begin{equation}
P(A) = P(A \cap B) = P(A/B)P(B)
\end{equation}

$P(A/B)=2/6$ because if you already know that there are two identical numbers in a row then A can happen in 2 ways (5,5) and (6,6) over the sample space (i,i), $1\leq i \leq 6.$

But P(B) is a little bit more tricky. I know that the answer is 1/7 (I run a simple program to compute this number) but for me is counter intuitive.

In that case the Expected value would be = 21 because I expect 1 "win" combination out of 21 rolls.

My confusion is that I would have answered 1/6 instead of 1/7 in $P(B)$ because, no matter what number came out from the first dice, the second has 1/6 probability to match that number. Why this intuition fails? I know the answer is in [2] but I still can not handle the intuition on this.

A generalization of this result can be found here:
[Expected number of rolls until a number appears $k$ times](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69373/expected-number-of-rolls-until-a-number-appears-k-times)

Moreover, this problem is often to get confused with the 1/36 probability of throwing two dices simultaneously.

Links where to the discussion of this topic:

[-] [If you roll a fair six sided die twice, what's the probability that you get the same number both times?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598808/if-you-roll-a-fair-six-sided-die-twice-whats-the-probability-that-you-get-the)

[-] [Why are the probability of rolling the same number twice and the probability of rolling pairs different?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1181129/why-are-the-probability-of-rolling-the-same-number-twice-and-the-probability-of)

Comment: What quantity are you trying to compute? Some of the links refer to problems asking for the "*expected* number of rolls until ...", while you seem to be trying to compute the probability of some event (two consecutive 6s or consecutive 5s, but in how many rolls?)

Comment: It is very hard to follow what you wrote.  You start out asking about an expected number of turns, but then you start computing some probability or other.

Comment: Yes I know, but in this case if the probability is 1/7 it means the expected number of rolls have to be 7. Isnt it?

Comment: The probability of what is $\frac 17$?  As you say, the probability that two consecutive throws match is obviously $\frac 16$.

Comment: ok I will edit the question.

Comment: I think it is best to introduce a few states.  Let $S_{\emptyset}$ be the state in which the prior throw was not a  $5$ or a $6$, $S_{5}$ is the state in which the prior throw was a $5$ and $S_6$ the state in which the prior throw was a $6$.  Let $E_{\emptyset}, E_5, E_6$ be the expected number of rolls it will take to finish given that you are in the relevant state.  Now work out simple relations between these.

Comment: @lulu I have to roll 7 times the dice in order to have two equal numbers. This is the heart of my confussion. I would have expected to have to roll 6 times the dice to have two equal numbers not 7.

Comment: The first roll doesn't "count" since it is impossible for the first roll to be the second term in a double.  That is why it is $7$ instead of $6$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118419/discussion-between-federico-vega-and-lulu).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sort of thing can easily be handled with states, and the symmetry makes it especially easy in this case.

There are three states where care about:  $ S_5, S_6,S_{\emptyset}$ according to whether the prior throw was a $5$, a $6$, or neither (we let $S_{\emptyset}$ include the starting state as well).  Symmetry tells us that we expect it to take the same number of rolls to finish from $S_5$ as it does from $S_6$, let $B$ denote that expected number.  Let $A$ denote the expected number starting from $S_{\emptyset}$, so the answer to the problem is $A$.

Considering the possible outcomes if you are in $S_{\emptyset}$ we see that $$A=\frac 13\times (B+1)+\frac 23\times (A+1)$$

Similarly, thinking about the possible outcomes if you are in $S_5$ or $S_6$ we see that $$B=\frac 16\times 1+\frac 16\times (B+1)+\frac 23\times (A+1)$$

Solving that system of equations yields $$A=21\quad \&\quad B=18$$ so the answer is $\boxed {21}$.

Comment: if the problem is modified to be either 55 or 6, how can we use this approach to proceed?

Comment: @WWSS  Just the same way, only now $6$ is an end state.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to solve the problem by finding the probability that two consecutive throws are either both $5$ or both $6$, and then taking one over this probability. Similar to how the expected number of flips it takes to get heads when $P(heads)=p$ is $1/p$. However, this does not work here, since the sequences of pairs of flips are not independent.

---

Let $X$ be the number of rolls it takes to get two fives or two sixes in a row. Starting with zero rolls, three things can happen:

- Your first roll is between $1$ and $4$. In this case, the number of subsequent roll has the same distribution as $X$.
- You first roll is $5$ or $6$, and your second roll is different from the first roll. Again, the number of subsequent rolls is $X$.
- You first two rolls are both fives or both sixes. Here, $X=2$.

We get that
$$
X\stackrel{d}=
\begin{cases}
X+1 & \text{with probability }\frac{2}{3} \\
X+2 & \text{with probability }\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac56 \\
2 & \text{with probability }\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac16 \\
\end{cases}\tag{*}
$$
Here is the interpretation of the above equality; $X$ has the same distribution as a random variable which is equal to one of the three options above, selected with the given probabilities independently of $X$.

Now, taking expectations of both sides, you get
$$
E[X] = \frac23 \cdot E[X+1] + \frac13\cdot\frac56 \cdot E[X+2] + \frac13\cdot\frac16 \cdot 2
$$
This lets you solve for $E[X]$.

---

As a side note, $(*)$ also implies that
$$
f(X)\stackrel{d}=
\begin{cases}
f(X+1) & \text{with probability }\frac{2}{3} \\
f(X+2) & \text{with probability }\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac56 \\
f(2) & \text{with probability }\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac16 \\
\end{cases}
$$
for any function $f$. Using $f(x)=x^2$, then taking expectations, lets you find $E[X^2]$, and therefore $\text{Var}(X)$. Using $f(x)=e^{tx}$ lets you find the full moment generating function of $X$.